# Объясните пожалуйста рекурсию в данном примере!

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, чистый-код

Объясните пожалуйста, зачем второй цикл. Если без него, то в **res** попадают просто массивы, но по моей логике, там должны оказаться значения. При этом если это не массив, а к примеру **res** изначально будет строкой, то туда попадают именно значения, как на втором примере. У меня руки опускаются.

```js
let a = [[[2]], [2], [[3]], [4]];

function flatten(array) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      const flat = flatten(array[i]);

      for (let j = 0; j < flat.length; j++) {
        res.push(flat[j]);
      }
    } else {
      res.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return res;
}


console.log(flatten(a));
```

```js
let a = [[[2]], [2], [[3]], [4]];
function fn(arg) {
  let res = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arg[i])) {
      let y = fn(arg[i]);

      res+=(y);
    } else {
      res+=(arg[i]);
    }
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(fn(a));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попытаюсь:
Для удобства пометил цифрами разные этапы рекрусии

```
function flatten(array) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {   (1)
      const flat = flatten(array[i]);    (2)

      for (let j = 0; j < flat.length; j++) {
        res.push(flat[j]);   (3)
      }
    } else {
      res.push(array[i]);   (4)
    }
  }

  return res;    (5)
}
```

У нас есть массив с элементам:
`let a = [[[2, 3, 7]], [2], [[3]], [4]];`

Допустим, что мы идем по рекурсии и спускаемся вниз. И вот мы дошли до массива `[[2, 3, 7]]`.

Идя по функции мы проходим по пути 1 - 2 - 3 - 5.

Рассмотрим  путь 1 - 2 - 3 подробнее, чтоб разобраться зачем нам еще один цикл:

1. (1) Проверяем `[[2, 3, 7]]`, что внутри массива находится еще один массив `[2, 3, 7]`.
2. (2) Запускаем новую функцию (При каждой инициализации у нас создается новый, ПУСТОЙ массив `res`).

   1. (1) проверяем, что `[2, 3, 7]` каждый из элементов массива не является             вложенным массивом.
   2. (4) в массив `res` пихаем все элементы из `[2, 3, 7]`. Т.е. вернется нам массив `[2, 3, 7]` **
3. (3) Мы перебираем вернувшийся массив `[2, 3, 7]` и точно также пихаем все его элементы в `res`. Тут важно отметить, что мы вернулись назад и поднялись на одну ступень вверх и в массиве `res` уже могут быть другие элементы, кроме тех, что мы в него добавляем.
   А теперь давайте вспомним, что изначальный массив `[[2, 3, 7]]` был частью  другого массива.
   Зачем нужен второй цикл? Да чтоб если у нас на месте элемента в массиве оказался еще один массив, мы бы его по элементу запихали в `res`, и продолжили в `res` добавлять другие элементы, не являющиеся массивом.

Почему во втором примере такого нет?
Потому что в первом примере нам возвращается массив элементов `[2, 3 ,7]`, и мы его перебираем по одному и добавляем в итоговый.
Во втором примере строка, ее перебирать не нужно и достаточно использовать сложение.

Если хотите сделать первый вариант похожим на второй со строкой, то можете использовать `spread` оператор:

```js
let a = [[[2]], [2], [[3]], [4]];

function flatten(array) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      const flat = flatten(array[i]);      
      res.push(...flat);
    } else {
      res.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(flatten(a));
```

Comment: Т.е., на этой строке возвращается: const flat = flatten(array[i]);=>(в случае с первым элементом - [2, 3, 7]), после выполнения : <const res = [2, 3, 7]> а уже пушатся в ключевой res уже по элементам : 2, 3, 7, (что бы не пушить сам массив)т.е. для этого и нужен второй цикл. Я правильно понял?)

Comment: да, вы все правильно поняли

Comment: Вы не представляете, насколько я вам благодарен!)Я около пяти часов пытался с дефтулсом разъяснить себе эту логику.) Спасибо большое!!)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пожалуйста отметьте его как верны)